# What exactly is Common Language Runtime

Tags: c#

What exactly is  Common Language Runtime in Dot Net. Is it an exe or dll. Can I see common  language runtime in task manager. Where is it located.

Answer (score 0):

You should first look up in google before posting here.. But here it goes:

**What is it?**

The .NET Framework provides a run-time environment called the common language runtime, which runs the code and provides services that make the development process easier.

**Where is it located?.**

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727

Of course the last part depends on your version.

Comment: ngen.exe is not the CLR.

Comment: O-O... You right, deleting that part.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I was asked multiple times in interview what exactly it is. I thought it is MScoree.dll or MSCorlib.dll. But again the question goes can i see it in task manager( if it is a process). Or is it group of dlls which does all the jobs of runtime.